# os.path.exists() throws error in Windows, not in Pycharm or Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, pycharm

This is my first question on SO :D
Im currently working on some Code. The problem is, following code works in Pycharm and in Ubuntu...but not in Windows.

```
import os, os.path
import configparser
if os.path.exists('config') and os.stat("config/config.ini").st_size>0:
 #do something
else:
 os.makedirs('config')
        password = input("Password: ")
        ip = input("IP Server: ")
        clientname = input("(choosen) Clientname: ")
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config['DEFAULT'] = {'User': user, 'ServerIP': ip, 'Clientname': clientname}
        with open('config/config.ini', 'w+') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
```

Windows Error[WinError2] File not found config/config.ini

On the other handside, does Pycharm and Ubuntu do what they have to do.
Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: there's probably an empty `config` directory somewhere (the current dirs are different depending on the way you're running it). Use `os.path.getsize()` to avoid calling `stat`. Your program probably crashed in the second section, leaving the `config` directory empty.

Comment: The script folder is empty. But your solution works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you comparing Windows and Ubuntu with PyCharm? The formers are operating systems, and PyCharm is a Python IDE. Using PyCharm or not will not make any difference.

Comment: @abccd It works in Pycharm Console. But it doesnt work in python shell on windows. BUT it works in python shell on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a current directory difference between the way you're running the code (the code depends on the current directory, which isn't really a good thing, either make it depend from the script location with `os.path.dirname(__file__)` or from user directory (`os.path.expanduser("~")`, works on Windows & Linux)

It reveals that your code isn't robust to the fact that `config` can be empty, for instance, if the second part crashes *before* creating the `.ini` file.

To make it more robust check if the file exists and not empty (not optimal, 2 `stat` calls, but ...) and you have to add an extra check in the second part to create the dir if doesn't exist.

I would do:

```
  config_file = "config/config.ini"
  if os.path.exists(config_file) and os.path.getsize(config_file):
     # do something
  else:
    config_dir = os.path.dirname(config_file)
    if not os.path.isdir(config_dir):
        os.makedirs('config')
    # now do the rest to create .ini file, the dir exists
```

also avoid using `'w+'` mode, you just want to create a new file, use `'w'`

Comment: Permission Error[Errno 13] Permission denied "config/config.ini"

Comment: Start cmd as Administrator

Comment: don't. Use absolute paths I'm mentionning in the start of my answer.

Comment: Ok. I edit my Code to your answer. But i found some strange behaviour.
script.py->open with: python ->Error Code, cant open something or something isnt there
But when i change my default programm for .py files from Pycharm to Python.....it works.